# Scheme: Returning two largest numbers from a set of three numbers

Tags: scheme, sicp

I am supposed to write a function that prints the sum of squares of the two greater numbers out of a set of given three numbers.

I have handled the situation rather clumsily. Instead of writing a function that returns the two largest numbers out of a set of 3, I have written the function so that expressions reduce to the two required numbers. # SSL function.

The reason I had to do this was that I *could not write a LISP function that could return multiple values together, and I could not write a LISP function that could read two values as an argument.*

**Is there a way that I can abstract out the calculation of the largest number in some other procedure?**

```
(define
    (min a b)
    (if (> a b) b a)
)

(define
    (max a b)
    (if (< a b) b a)
)


(define
    (square a)
    ( * a a)
)



(define 
    (ssl a b c)
    (+ (square (max a b)) (square (max (min a b) c)))
)
```

Comment: You might enjoy this: [https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.scheme/pMpDFJ12sTo](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.lang.scheme/pMpDFJ12sTo).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As usual, it's a good idea to split the problem in subproblems which are easier to solve; I'll explain how to write a solution and at the same time I'll answer your questions. First, let's find out the two greatest numbers out of three and return them in a list - this is a simple, portable way to return multiple values:

```
(define (max-two a b c)
  (if (>= a b)
      (if (>= b c)
          (list a b)
          (list a c))
      (if (>= a c)
          (list b a)
          (list b c))))
```

Now let's write a procedure that takes as input two numbers, squares them and then adds the results - this is how we can declare a function that receives multiple values as arguments:

```
(define (sum-square x y)
  (+ (* x x) (* y y)))
```

Finally, let's compose the procedures to obtain the answer - we'll use `apply` for applying `sum-square` (a function that receives two parameters) to the result returned by `max-two` (a list with two elements) - this is how we can process the multiple values returned by `max-two`:

```
(define (sum-max a b c)
  (apply sum-square (max-two a b c)))
```

The result is as expected:

```
(sum-max 3 1 2)
=> 13
```

Answer (score 10):

This is exercise 1.3 from the [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) ♥ (Structure and Interpretation of Computer Programs) book.

At this point in the book lists have not been introduced, and there is no need to use them. This is my solution (I am studying from the SICP book at the moment).

The first thing would be to come up with the largest number of the three numbers:

```
(define (getlargest a b c) 
  (if (> (if (> a b) a b) c) (if (> a b) a b) c)
  )
```

getlargest reads:

- If a is greater than b, then a, otherwise b
- Take the result from the previous step and compare it against c in the same way.
- Return either
  the largest number between a and b, or return c, if c happens to be
  bigger than both a and b.

The second thing would be to come up with the middle number:

```
(define (getmiddle a b c)
  (cond ((= (getlargest a b c) a) (if (> b c) b c))
        ((= (getlargest a b c) b) (if (> a c) a c))
        ((= (getlargest a b c) c) (if (> a b) a b))
        )
  )
```

getmiddle reads:

- Use getlargest to determine if a or b or c is the largest number.
- If a is the largest number, compare b against c and return the largest of b and c; similarly,
- If b is the largest, compare a against c and return the largest of a and c
- If c is the largest, compare a against b and return the largest of a and b

Now we need a function to compute sum of the squares of two numbers:

```
(define (sqrsum x y)
  (+ (* x x) (* y y))
  )
```

And finally, the main function:

```
(define (main a b c) 
  (sqrsum (getlargest a b c) (getmiddle a b c))
  )
```

We could "blackbox" the whole thing by putting everything inside main:

```
(define (main a b c) 
 (define (getlargest) 
    (if (> (if (> a b) a b) c) (if (> a b) a b) c)
  )

  (define (getmiddle)
  (cond ((= (getlargest) a) (if (> b c) b c))
        ((= (getlargest) b) (if (> a c) a c))
        ((= (getlargest) c) (if (> a b) a b))
        )
  )

  (define (sqrsum x y)
    (+ (* x x) (* y y))
  )

  (sqrsum (getlargest) (getmiddle))
  )
```

Comment: Alternatively, can't we just do `(define (getsmallest a b c)
(if (< (if (< a b) a b) c) (if (< a b) a b) c))`, and do the `squaresum` on whatever 2 integers that aren't smallest? I think it is slightly shorter because we won't have to find both largest and middle :)

Answer (score 4):

First of all, this comment does not address the OP's problem, instead, it explains my observations and provides a different approach to the given problem.

---

Here are the two methods that I can think of,

1. Direct method: Trying to find and evaluate the *two larger numbers* that was originally asked in the question.
2. Indirect method: Trying to find and *ignore the sole smallest number*, then evaluate the remaining two numbers.

I'd prefer the second method because it involves finding a single number while the other asks a bit more ― I can imagine a scenario in which we are asked to evaluate the sum of squares of the 7 largest numbers in a list of 8, for example.

---

First, I'm going to define the necessary procedures for the final evaluation

```
(define (square x)
    (* x x))

(define (sum-of-squares x y)
    (+ (square x) (square y)))

(define (largest2-sum-of-squares x y z)
          ;;; x is excluded
    (cond ((and (<= x y) (<= x z)) (sum-of-squares y z))
          ;;; y is excluded
          ((and (<= y x) (<= y z)) (sum-of-squares x z))
          ;;; z is excluded
          ((and (<= z x) (<= z y)) (sum-of-squares x y)))
          ;;; Note: It's also tempting to go for (else (sum-of-squares x y)))
```

Then, run a few tests on the `largest2-sum-of-squares` procedure on [STk](https://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~scheme/)

```
STk> (largest2-sum-of-squares 1 2 3)
13
STk> (largest2-sum-of-squares 1 1 3)
10
STk> (largest2-sum-of-squares -3 4 0)
16
```

Comment: This is a good approach, but you should definitely "_go for `(else (sum-of-squares x y)))`_". There is no reason to waste cycles on two more comparisons, and using `else` communicates the meaning more clearly: there is only one possibility available for this branch of the `cond`. But +1 for the good approach.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but I haven't seen this approach, so here we go:

```lisp
;;; Standard helper functions.
(define (square x) (* x x))
(define (max a b) (if (> a b) a b))
(define (min a b) (if (< a b) a b))
;;; I could write these ones in place but it would make it hard to read.
(define (max-of-3 a b c) (max (max a b) c))
(define (min-of-3 a b c) (min (min a b) c))
;;; To find the middle, add them all together, and remove top and bottom, you
;;; should be left with the middle. (ex. (3 + 2 + 1) - 3 - 1 ).
(define (mid-of-3 a b c)
  (- (+ a b c) (max-of-3 a b c) (min-of-3 a b c)))
;;; The solution here is fairly standard and legible.
(define (solution x y z)
  (+ (square (max-of-3 x y z)) (square (mid-of-3 x y z))))
```

I am separating the logic and naming thing just so that it's easier to read, but you can always replace the function bodies for their function names, but honestly that would look like a mess, and it's much harder to understand than this.

---

That being said, a more "functional" approach would be to `sort -> take right 2 -> map to x^2 -> reduce with +`. But of course all of these operations have not been introduced yet in SICP (not even how to work with lists or recursion).

Answer (score 0):

Define a procedure that takes three numbers as arguments and returns the sum of the squares of the two larger numbers. Not used list yet. Just used define and condition expresion.

```
(define (square x) (* x x))

(define (sum-of-square x y) (+ (square x) (square y)))

(define (largest a b c)
  (cond ((and (> a b) (> a c)) a)
        ((and (> b a) (> b c)) b)
        ((and (> c b) (> c a)) c)))

(define (larger a b)
  (if (< a b)
      b
      a))

(define (sum-of-two-larger-square a b c)
     (cond ((= (largest a b c) a) (sum-of-square a (larger b c)))
            ((= (largest a b c) b) (sum-of-square b (larger a c)))
            ((= (largest a b c) c) (sum-of-square c (larger a b)))) )
```

Then test the procedures

```
(largest 1 2 3)
(larger 1 2)
(square 3)
(sum-of-square 2 3)
(two-larger-of-three 1 2 3)
(sum-of-two-larger-square 1 2 3)
(sum-of-two-larger-square 12 45 100)
(sum-of-square 45 100)
```